# Cannot play http stream with nvlc .net

Tags: c#, .net, http, stream, vlc

I try to use nvlc API to play http stream but I have the following problem:

I can play local video:

```
IMediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
IMedia media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(@"C:\Videos\Movie.wmv");
IVideoPlayer player = factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>();
player.WindowHandle = panel1.Handle;
player.Open(media);
player.Events.MediaEnded += new EventHandler(Events_MediaEnded);
player.Events.TimeChanged += new EventHandler<TimeChangedEventArgs>(Events_TimeChanged);
player.Play();
```

But cannot play http stream:

```
IMediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
IMedia media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(@"http://90.189.198.75:1234/udp/233.7.70.84:5000");
IVideoPlayer player = factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>();
player.WindowHandle = panel1.Handle;
player.Open(media);
player.Events.MediaEnded += new EventHandler(Events_MediaEnded);
player.Events.TimeChanged += new EventHandler<TimeChangedEventArgs>(Events_TimeChanged);
player.Play();
```

Thank you for your attention and your time!

EDIT:

After a long search for a solution on the internet, stream suddenly started without any problems. With the original code! Probably probem was in stream but I do not know why there was no problem with VLC player. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: When you say you cannot play the stream - what happens?  Do you see errors?

Comment: Yes, there are no errors.

Comment: Just been looking through [the docs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC) - have you configured logging?  May be something in there to look at - looks like you need to add a section to your config file for NLog

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the cause of your problem... Colon `:` is a reserved character in URLs and should be escaped

```
http://90.189.198.75:1234/udp/233.7.70.84%3A5000
```

Comment: :5000 is a http port of stream and should not be escaped.

Comment: Yeah, this part looks ok - the [docs on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC) have this example: `IMedia media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(@"udp://@172.16.10.1:19005");`;

Comment: Ok... but that's not the URL you have. You have an HTTP url that appears to have a second udp "url" embedded within it. The port of the stream is 1234, ***not*** port 5000. Whatever is at 90.189.198.75:1234 should unescape the "embedded" udp "url". Standards dictate that HTTP urls should not use `:` for anything other than the port number. In this url, the port number is **1234**. The last part of the url that *resembles* a port, is not a port number in terms of HTTP. It's just part of a url, and as such, using a colon in this context means you are presenting a broken URL.

Comment: @stoyanov The http port of the stream is clearly 1234, not 5000.

Comment: @spender Good spot - I ignored everything between a strange IP address and the final "port".

Comment: @spender You're right my mistake is in the case :|. But with escaped url nothing happens.

Comment: @stoyanov Are you sure that the URL you're using (whether escaped or not) is correct - do you have another way of verifying it?  It does look like an odd url.

Comment: @James Thorpe I play this url in vlc player.